# Can't create django app in Conda environment.

Tags: django, django-admin, conda

I have created a conda environment by typing the following `conda create --name testenv python` command from [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html).

Now one of my tutorials tells me to install Django which I happily did in the environment(That is the point of using environments right?, keeping dependencies straight) using `pip3 install django`.Post which I was told to do this `django-admin startproject mysite` Which didn't work. I am thinking because he was doing it in venv and I am in conda probably that's why(There is no venv folder in my test-app folder as well. Also I have already activated the environment). Every time I type the command `django-admin startapp mysite` I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/django-admin", line 18, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

How do I fix this? I have already installed Django. What more am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but if anyone is wondering the exact steps to create a Django application using conda, here it is

1. `conda create -n <nameoftheapplication> python=3.6`
2. `source activate <nameoftheapplication>` Note: For Windows just put activate
3. `pip install django`
4. `django-admin.py startproject <nameoftheapplication>`
5. `cd <nameoftheapplication>`
6. `ls`

You should see manage.py and a folder called `<nameoftheapplication>` which contains settings files.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, open the anaconda prompt in windows then go to the project directory and enter the following command:

1. conda create -n  python=3.6 anaconda
2. activate
3. pip install django
4. django-admin.py startproject
5. cd
6. python manage.py runserver

Then open web browser and enter the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to see django page.